# how to group by a number of ids in a postgres array

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am trying to select a row based upon a count of the nubmer of items in a Postgres array (represented as a text field in Postgres 9.4) and be able to select / group in Rails 4.2

I have the following tables:

```
 queryable_id | liked_count | users_who_like_ids 
--------------+-------------+--------------------
         2376 |           3 | {1,80,78,101, 188}
        18771 |           1 | {78,101, 123,125}
         1790 |           1 | {78}
         2257 |           1 | {78}
```

For example, I'd like to say select the and order by user_who_like_ids like

```
select * from items group by count(users_who_like_ids) where users_who_like_ids include (78,123,125)
```

How would I make this query? Would this type of query be supported in rails?

#### edit 1

here is the users_who_like_ids

```
 users_who_like_ids      | text[]                      | default '{}'::text[]
```

#### edit 2

It looks like this kinda works:

```
select queryable_id, liked_count, users_who_like_ids  from  queryables where users_who_like_ids  @> ARRAY['1','80'];
```

but this requires both 1 and 80

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you are looking for `array_length()`

```
select
  *
from 
  items
where
  users_who_like_ids @> ARRAY[78,123,125]
group by
  array_length(users_who_like_ids)
```

Note, that the `where` clause always belongs for the `group by` clause.

Comment: hmm... so something like that sounds like it would but I'm getting an error on the include statement. editing question... Wondering if it should be ingeter[] - first time using postgres arrays

Comment: Ah, yes, I was mislead. You need the `@>` operator instead of `includes`. Sorry, I'll edit my answer. And, yes, I have expected the array to be `integer[]`. If you plan to stick with `text[]`, just surround your numbers with single quotes: ARRAY['78','123','125']